# Merging US counties in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm doing research on US cotton price fluctuations from 1877-1930.

Here's the problem: my data is county-level, but county borders changed from 1877 to 1930!

To solve this, I plan to "aggregate up" to the smallest consistent unit (eg. if a county border splits, use the un-split original county as the unit of observation).

How can I do this on QGIS? I am using data from the Historical County Project here: http://publications.newberry.org/ahcbp/